# python runtime mismatch when trying to deploy a fastAPI app to vercel

Tags: python, fastapi, vercel, aws-serverless

i'm trying to deploy the app using vercel cli, but when i do it says my function has an invalid python version. now i checked with python --version and it appears my python is 3.11 and up to date, so where's the error coming from?

here's the console:

(venv) my/path$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.4
(venv) my/path$ vercel
Vercel CLI 31.2.3
  Inspect: https://vercel.com/name/project/projectid [1s]
Error: A Serverless Function has invalid python version: found runtime parameter of python3.6 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Serverless Function functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (python3.9) but needs at least python3.6 to build.

Comment: Even I am facing this the same today while trying to deploy the fastAPI app in vercel, did you get any lead on the same at your end?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar I did. mind sharing your vercel.json file contents for a reference? just remember to replace any sensitive details

Comment: Sure @LeeSkies, here is the vercel.json file which I am using in the project:
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      { "src": "main.py", "use": "@vercel/python" }
    ],
    "routes": [
      { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/main.py" }
    ],
  }

Comment: @ChandraShekhar right after "use": "@vercel/python" add this config object: "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" } (still inside "builds"). put your runtime - should be 3.9 or higher. i dont know if maxLambdaSize is needed in your case, just know if you tackle an error lambda size related  that you can add this to your configuration and play with the values there till it fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeeSkies, sure will give this a try. :)

Comment: @ChandraShekhar np m8, lemme know if it works

Comment: @LeeSkies it worked for me. You should post it as accepted answer. This is what I have. Below. 

`
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "/src/asgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": {
        "runtime": "3.11",
        "maxLambdaSize": "15mb"
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/asgi.py"
    }
  ]
}
`

swear to god. I fudged around for 2+ hours and even tried their fastapi template it didn't work. Had to use this instead.

Comment: @stanley_manley glad it worked for you! and you're absolutely right, I'll post it right away

Answer (score 3):

Adding the "runtime" property to the config seems to solve it:

```
"builds": [
    {"src": "app.py", "use": "@vercel/python", "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }}
],
```

note that the runtime should be python 3.9 or higher.